# Story of Mookambika Temple from Puranas

Tags: puranas, temple, devi, skanda-purana

[Mookambika Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mookambika) at Kollur, Karnataka is a temple dedicated to Mookambika Devi. The story of it goes like Devi killed Mookasura, so it is called Mookambika Devi. It is believed that the story of Mookambika temple at Kollur (Maharanya Puram) is narrated by Lord Siva to Skanda in Skanda Mahapuranam. Also [Sri Mookambika Ashtakam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8AgxQ_74Vs) is also believed to be from Skanda Purana. The deity looks as below

[image]

My question is Which Khanda and Chapter of Skanda Puranam has this story and the Ashtakam? Please provide some slokas and meanings.