# Are there multiple stories on Kolasura?

Tags: untagged

In [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8766/who-spoke-the-lakshmi-ashtakam-did-lakshmi-really-kill-kolhasura), Kolhasura is said to be killed by Lakshmi in Kolhapur. In [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15177/story-of-mookambika-temple-from-puranas), Goddess Mookambika is said to kill Kolasura at Kollur. Also, Goddess Kali kills him in [this version](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53431/is-true-goddess-kali-killed-two-demons-named-kolasura-and-ghorasura).

Are these stories different re-tellings of an earlier story?

Comment: They are actually diffrent asuras, but have same name.